# Make html text bold but not the ejs variable next to the text

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, ejs

[image]

How do I make the "Guest signed up" and "Guests attended" text bold (from image above) while keeping the values not bold? Here's what I have now:

```
          <li class="list-group-item">Guests signed up: <%= guestSignups %></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Guests attended: <%= guestAttends %></li>
```

I tried below and it dropped the values down one line and looked terrible.

```
          <li class="list-group-item fw-bold">Guests signed up: 
              <p class="fw-normal"><%= guestSignups %></p>
            </li>
          <li class="list-group-item fw-bold">Guests attended: 
            <p class="fw-normal"><%= guestAttends %></p>
            </li>
```

Comment: `p` is a block element. If you want it to be inline use something like `span`.

Comment: Genius. You nailed it. Thanks @skara9 !!

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the string around a b or strong tag

or even a `<span class="specialBoldFontClass">` with a custom class

```html
 <li class="list-group-item"><b>Guests signed up:</b> <%= guestSignups %></li>
<li class="list-group-item"><b>Guests attended:</b> <%= guestAttends %></li>
```